# Why this singleton implementation works?

Tags: c++, singleton

Today I saw this pattern for using Singleton and it confused me a lot.

```
class Singleton{
public:
    static Singleton& getInstance();
};

Singleton& Singleton::getInstance(){
    static Singeton instance;
    return instance;
}
int main(){
    Singleton &inst = Singleton::getInstance();
    Singleton &inst2 = Singleton::getInstance();
    std::cout << &inst << " " << &inst2;
}
```

The output of the pointers is the same. [Here](https://ideone.com/GuMQU6) is an example. I am really confused about it. I would expect every call to `getInstance()` to create a new (although static) instance of singleton. Could you please explain me the behaviour.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing another `static` keyword there?

Comment: The problem with this singleton implementation is that the destructor of `Singleton` will be called at the end of the program, which may lead to order-of-destruction issues if you have dependencies among singletons (the prototypical example being a "Log" singleton). Generally, you just want to prevent destruction by allocating the object with `new` and never calling `delete`, ideally prevent concurrency issues by explictly instantiating all singletons immediately in the main thread. And, of course, keep in mind that Singleton is an *extremely* overused design pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a reason you posted the source of your function here different than on the page you gave link to:

```
static Singleton& getInstance(){
  static Singleton instance;
  return instance;
}
```

Why does it work? The static local object `instance` in the function is created only once, the first time the function is called - that's because it's `static`. The next times you call the function it returns reference to the same object.

Comment: Yes, I figured that looking at the output, why that happens?

Comment: That's the rule of C++ (and C).

Comment: If you have a static local variable it gets initialized only once, the first time the function is called. It works different than for automatic variables, which a\re allocated on stack.

Comment: Yes, but a variable created static makes it to leave as long as the program runs, that's the only definition I know for static variables.

Comment: Also, not only does this implementation work, it also has nice properties, like it doesn't rely on static variable initialization order, and the singleton initialisation is thread-safe as of C++11.

Comment: How does the compiler know that the 2nd call is the 2nd call (and not the 1st one) and it doesn't have to create the variables again?

Comment: Exactly. A local static variable lives as long as the program runs, and it gets initialized only once - the first time you call the function. Notice that what you return from the function is a reference to the object - always the same one.

Comment: That's a detail of a particular implementation, not specified by the language standard.